# How to check whether an NSImage is GrayScale or RGB?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

Is there any way to check an NSImage's color type in OBJC? I wanna know whether the image is GrayScale or RGB. Any suggestions would help, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the image's color space (possibly from its underlying CGImage) you could determine the number of components in it. If its < 3 you have a monochrome image.

However an image could still be monochrome and have a color color space.

Comment: Thank's a lot! I've found the solution following your advice. I can change the NSImage into NSBitmapImageRep, and there's a property called "colorSpaceName" for NSBitmapImageRep. It will return a NSString which indicates the color space type of the image. That's actually what I want! Thanks!

Comment: As long as you know the source of your image will always use a monochrome color space. Personally I wouldn't use the name of the color space since that could change in the future--number of components should be accurate.